# Select All from Collection Where ID in List

Tags: c#, list, select, dapper

I'm just learning to use lambda expressions and was turned on to Dapper a couple days ago. I'm working on an app that populates a `listView` with usernames to be selected for some account maintenance. I'm having trouble with one part of sorting:

- I'm getting a collection of objects using a Dapper query and assigning it to the variable `Global.allUsers`.
- I have a list of IDs (`List<int> migrated`) that have already been used, and so don't need to appear in the `listView`
- I'm getting a list of all my users using the following:

  ```
  var  uniqUsers = Global.allUsers.OrderBy(n => n.lastNames).GroupBy(q => q.salesIDs);
  ```

To populate the `listView` with only the users who haven't been migrated, I need to select only those users without `q.salesIDs` in `migrated`. I just can't quite figure out if/how I can do this without using some kind of `foreach`. Seems like there should be a way to select it.

Granted, I'm looping through `uniqUsers` anyway, and populating the `listView` with values out of each object's properties. I can add a statement to check if the current ID is in `migrated`, but my gut is just telling me that I can do it with the select statement and save myself a step.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
 var  uniqUsers = Global.allUsers.Where(i => i.salesIDs not in migrated).OrderBy(n => n.lastNames).GroupBy(q => q.salesIDs);
```

but `i => i.salesIDs not in migrated` isn't cutting it.

Comment: Gut feeling was bang on.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed)" and "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what you need:

```
var uniqUsers = allUsers.Where(x => migrated.Contains(x.salesIDs))
                        .OrderBy(y => y.lastNames)
                        .GroupBy(z => z.salesIDs).SelectMany(v => v).ToList();
```

Gets all users where the `salesID` is in `migrated`, then orders by `lastNames` and then groups by the `salesID`. The `SelectMany()` will project the elements to a sequence, the `ToList()` will  enumerate the results.

Comment: Thanks, @DGibbs! I realized, though that I messed up my example. Yours works if I want everything in `migrated`, which is what my example showed. Can I negate the `Where` clause? `where does not contain`?

Comment: Nm. Just found it. `var  uniqUsers = Global.allUsers.Where(i => !migrated.Contains(i.salesIDs)).OrderBy(n => n.lastNames).GroupBy(q => q.salesIDs);` Thanks!!!

Comment: Yep you can negate the condition with a `!` operator. Though this line in your op is a little confusing `"I need to select only those users with q.salesIDs in migrated"` which suggests the opposite.